# Use of operator= combined with new operator

Tags: c++, copy, assign

I was wondering how to write the operator `=` so that the existing allocated memory on a variable be deallocated.

For instance, in the code below, when reassigning the `x` pointer `x = new ClassExample(4)`, the old `x->a` memory would be deallocated.

Apparently, when using `new`, the operator `=` doesn't apply (it's only for *already existing* values).

Is there any method of doing this (free old memory when alloc new memory)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class ClassExample {
public:
    int* a;
    ClassExample& operator= (const ClassExample& rightSide) {
       //..... 
    }

    ClassExample(int val) {
         a = new int(val); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClassExample* x = new ClassExample(2);
    x = new ClassExample(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assignment operator is not called in this case, because you are using pointers and not direct instances. And also remember that allocated memory is never automatically free'd, you have to do it. Using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) helps.

Comment: Actually, in a case like this, *why* are you using pointers? And I don't only mean the `ClassExample` pointers in `main`, but the member pointer `a` in the class as well! The rules you should follow is: 1. Don't use pointers. 2. If you have to use pointers, don't. 3. If you still have to use pointers then use smart pointers.

Comment: Think about exception safety too

Answer (score 2):

Never break this rule: every `new` has to be balanced with a `delete`.

You could use a smart pointer to achieve what you want, or, in your specific case something simpler:

Briefly, you build a `WrappedPtr<T>` template class for data type T, which holds a `T*` pointer. As a starting point, you can define an assignment operator which will delete a currently wrapped object before taking the new one as its member data. You will need to take care with copy construction; or even forbid it.

A true smart pointer will also implement reference counting in some way.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 0):

The operator= means you are changing the value inside your current object.
Here, you are just changing the pointer x.

The way you could do it is :

```
ClassExample x(2);
x = ClassExample(4);
```

Or, in your case, something like:

```
ClassExample* x = new ClassExample(2);
*x = *(new ClassExample(4));
```

This last one will introduce leak in your program, so do NOT use it.
Of course, you can use something in between, like:

```
ClassExample* x = new ClassExample(2);
*x = ClassExample(4);
```

This one won't leak.

Comment: It might not leak the val, but calling new should be matched by calling delete otherwise it *will* leak

Comment: There is no problem with my last example, the first "ClassExample(2)" will still exists, and the "ClassExample(4)" will be destructed once the copy is done. Then, of course, the 'x' will have to be deleted by the end of the program.